# Writing a function to construct a list of descending natural numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm experimenting with Haskell and I'm trying to iteratively construct a list.

```
fibList :: Int -> [Int]
fibList n = if n == 1 then [1]
            else [n]:fibList (n - 1)
```

My ultimate goal is to construct a list of fibonacci numbers, but for now I'm just trying to build a descending list of integers. However, when I try to load this code into ghci I get the following error

```
fibonacci.hs:9:22: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘[Int]’
      Expected type: [[Int]]
        Actual type: [Int]
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘fibList (n - 1)’
      In the expression: [n] : fibList (n - 1)
      In the expression: if n == 1 then [1] else [n] : fibList (n - 1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

got it working. Thank you all!

```
fibList :: Int -> [Int]
fibList n = if n == 1 then [1]
            else n:fibList (n - 1)
```

also got it working as a list of fibonacci numbers!

```
fibList :: Int -> [Int]
fibList n
    | n <= 0 = error "n must be a positive integer"
    | n == 1 = [1]
    | n == 2 = [1, 1]
    | otherwise = ( prev_term + twice_prev_term ) : prior_fib_list
    where prior_fib_list = fibList (n - 1)
          prev_term = prior_fib_list !! 0
          twice_prev_term = prior_fib_list !! 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't `cons` a list of numbers to a list of numbers. You can `cons` a number to a list of numbers, though:

```
fun 1 = [1]
fun n = n : (fun (n - 1))
```

Comment: To append lists use `(++)`, example: `[n] ++ fun (n - 1)`.  But using cons `(:)` as in the in the answer is surely preferred in this case.

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is prepend a list of numbers `[n]:`

to a list of numbers `[1]`

And that's not how the cons operator works, as it can only prepend the element of a list to that list, eg.

`[a]` to `[[a]]`

or `a` to `[a]`